# Is it possible to add slices to bubble charts in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to build a bubble chart in Google Charts with another dimension. The first two dimensions are the X and Y axis, the third is the volume (size of bubble), and the fourth are slices in the bubble. Each slice should depict what it represents. Here's an example:

[image]

I have only seen the normal bubble chart from Google Charts with no slices. Is there a way around so I can create this type of visualization?

Comment: no standard option for adding slices to the bubbles, but you could overlay each bubble with an actual pie chart, using the following chart methods --> `getChartLayoutInterface().getXLocation` & `getYLocation` -- similar to this answer which places images --> [attach image on edge of google line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771) -- you could also inspect the bubble chart's svg, to determine the size of the bubbles...

Comment: @WhiteHat How do I get the size of the bubble chart to apply on the pie chart?

Comment: when the bubble chart's `'ready'` event fires, inspect the chart's svg, each bubble will be drawn with a `<circle>` element -- the `r` (radius) attribute will give you the size...

Comment: if you sort the data table by the x-axis before drawing the bubble chart, the `<circle>` elements in the svg dom will be in the same order as the rows in the data table...

Comment: @WhiteHat Sorry for the delay, but how do I append an actual pie chart on the graph? Instead of appending an image, do I append a div? How does it get drawn, I'm trying to replicate your example of the images, but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: @WhiteHat Here's my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nL4sjam0/1/ I created the div and tried adding it to the page, but for some reason it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @WhiteHat Correct me if i'm wrong, but don't we want to append it to the line chart's div? The images were appended to the line chart's div, why shouldn't the newly created div? Also, even when I replace container with document, I'm still getting an eror

Comment: @WhiteHat It says "this.ce is not a function" https://jsfiddle.net/nL4sjam0/2/

Comment: `new` keyword wasn't used on new pie chart --> [jsfiddle.net/nL4sjam0/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/nL4sjam0/3/)

Comment: @WhiteHat But why aren't they position on the line in the line graph just like the line graph with the images?

Comment: they are, but the pie chart's height & width need to be adjusted, change the background color from `'transparent'` and you'll see...

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes, I noticed that after playing around with it. I'm trying to get the chart to be displayed on top by positioning it with `top: 0px`, but for some reason it is not adjusting

Comment: the chart doesn't fill the container by default, see options for `chartArea` in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765947/coloring-google-stepped-area-charts/43766131#43766131)...

Comment: @WhiteHat I'm trying to put the bubble charts exactly on the bubbles. Adjusting the options still does not get me to a solution, here's my updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0g9shbk/ is there a way I can put the pie charts exactly on the bubbles?

Comment: you'll need to adjust the x,y position to account for the white space (transparent space) around the pie chart